# What do 'compromise' and 'realize' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

What do 'compromise' and 'realize' mean in these lyrics of "Things You've Never Done" by Passenger?

> You were so proud,
> She'd call you so loud,
> But you'd never know.
> Now that you're wiser,
> You'd never compromise her,
> Every day you'd realise her,
> But this bird has flown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what "compromise" means. My guess would be something like using the person as a pawn, taking advantage of the person somehow for your personal gain. It could have a sexual connotation, too.

While it's not crystal clear what "realise" means, it probably means "appreciate" or "not take for granted."

BTW, your headline should read:

What **do** "compromise" and "realize" mean in this context?

Comment: It's a pop song. The words fit the rhythm, and they rhyme. That can be more important than literal meaning.